Detecting if the caps lock is on
For my app's needs, I need detect if the caps lock is on, on the virtual keyboard, and update the ui with a related icon.
Thing is, I cannot find any info on how to monitor for such detail.
Any help? I am using kotlin and jetpack compose, and the icon I wanna show will be inside a textinput
Could not really find any info, so I have barely tried anything

Not possible.  The Android OS doesn't have the concept of caps lock.  If a software keyboard has such a button, it is 100% handled by them internally.  That state is not shared in any way.  Controlling things like capitalization is a feature of the keyboard app, not of the Android OS.

Would detecting the click of a certain button be possible?

No.  The soft keyboard doesn't report button taps to the OS.  The only thing the softkeyboard reports is when it wants to send or delete text.  You could detect when text is being sent, but it may be (frequently is) more than 1 letter, and will already be captialized or not (whatever the keyboard thinks it should be).  The OS doesn't enforce the idea of buttons on the keyboard-  in fact many keyboards don't use them at all (think of a swipe to type system, no buttons are being tapped).

I don't known if Android provide API to detect the capslock but with "TextWatcher", u can detect UpperCase :
editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    override fun onTextChanged(input: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        val cInput = input?.toString()
        if (Pattern.matches("[A-Z]", cInput)) {
            Log.e("", "Caps lock is actived")
        } else if (Pattern.matches("[a-z]", cInput)) {
            Log.e("", "Caps lock is disabled")
        }
    }
})


Since you said compose:
modifier = modifier
   .onPreInterceptKeyBeforeSoftKeyboard {
   /* isCapsOnState = */it.nativeKeyEvent.isCapsLockOn
   false
},

Remember to keep false so that the interception doesn't stop other listeners below it from using the key event. If you feeling frisky, use this answer to simulate a keyEvent, but no gurantee that the Caps Lock Meta will be in that event

This won't work.  ALmost no keyboards send key events, instead they use commitText calls.  It would work with a hardware USB keyboard, but not a software keyboard.
